# validation is not working in cake php if retrieve data from other model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i have table "car_types" ,a Controller users_controller, model Car_type and action url

```
localhost/carsdirectory/users/dashboard
```

dashboard.ctp(view)

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->create('Users', array('type' => 'file', 'action' => 'dashboard')); ?>
 <select>
 <?php foreach($car_type as $key => $val) { ?>
 <option value="" selected="selected">select</option>
 <option value="<?php echo $val['Car_type']['id']; ?>">
 <?php echo $val['Car_type']['car_type']; ?>
 </option>
 <?php } ?>
 </select>
 <?php echo $this->Form->end(array('label' => 'Submit', 'name' => 'Submit', 'div' => array('class' => 'ls-submit')));?>
```

Car_type.php(model)

```
 class Car_type extends AppModel
   {
   var $name = 'Car_type';

   var $validate = array(

   'car_type' => array(

       'rule' =>'notEmpty',
       'message' => 'Plz select type.'
         )
     ); 
    }
```

users_controller.php(controller)

```
  public function dashboard(){

      $this->loadModel('Car_type'); // your Model name => Car_type

      $this->set('car_type', $this->Car_type->find('all'));

   }
```

but when i click submit button i want to show msg(Plz select type) and right now it's not working i know i have problem in my code not i m not able to sort out it so plz help me

thanks in advance,  vikas tyagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This validation rule is to validate when you add some car type, not user.

For this, you need put validation in User model from car_type_id field:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';

    var $validate = array(
        'car_type_id' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'message' => 'Please, select car type.'
        )
    );
}
```

And your form:

```
$this->Form->input('car_type_id', array('options' => $car_type, 'empty' => '- select -'));
```

Your Controller can be simply:

```
$this->set('car_type', $this->User->Car_type->find('all'));
```

However, do not know if this is your entire code to confirm the relationship between these two models are correct.

Comment: but i have created other model class Car_type

Comment: When you need add user with a car type, your validation has to be the model User, not in Car_type. Can you show more code for us on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)? Like your whole User and Car_type model and structure of these tables in database?

Comment: this is action url localhost/carsdirectory/users/dashboard and in this page i have select field, in this select field i m fetching data from car_types table(i have two field table 1. id 2.Car_type) that's why i have made other model Car_type

Answer (score 0):

Considering that it's data, you should store the list of valid choices in the model.

```
var $carType= array('a' => 'Honda', 'b' => 'Toyota', 'c' => 'Ford');
```

You can get that variable in the Controller simply like this:

```
$this->set('fieldAbcs', $this->MyModel->carType);
```

Unfortunately you can't simply use that variable in the rule declaration for the inList rule, since rules are declared as instance variables and those can only be initialized statically (no variables allowed). The best way around that is to set the variable in the Constructor:

```
var $validate = array(
    'carType' => array(
        'allowedChoice' => array(
            'rule' => array('inList', array()),
            'message' => 'Pls select type.'
        )
    )
);

function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);

    $this->validate['carType']['allowedChoice']['rule'][1] =
    array_keys($this->fieldAbcChoices);
}
```